# Error when debugging sample in OPENCV Camera Calibration using OPEN CV. Assertion failed ( count >=0) cornersubpix. Opencv 3.2 with VS15

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, visual-c++, camera-calibration, assertions

I am getting an error when using `Camera_Calibration.cpp` on OpenCv Tutorial (photo). i running it in release mode.

[image].

I got assertion fail. I debugged this project by command window with in_VID5.xml

in_VID5.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
 <opencv_storage>  
 <Settings>  
  <!-- Number of inner corners per a item row and column. (square, circle) -->  
  <BoardSize_Width>7</BoardSize_Width>  
  <BoardSize_Height>5</BoardSize_Height>  
  <!-- The size of a square in some user defined metric system (pixel, millimeter)-->  
  <Square_Size>30</Square_Size>  
  <!-- The type of input used for camera calibration. One of: CHESSBOARD CIRCLES_GRID ASYMMETRIC_CIRCLES_GRID -->  
  <Calibrate_Pattern>"CHESSBOARD"</Calibrate_Pattern>  
  <!-- The input to use for calibration.   
           To use an input camera -> give the ID of the camera, like "1"  
           To use an input video -> give the path of the input video, like "/tmp/x.avi"  
           To use an image list  -> give the path to the XML or YAML file containing the list of the images, like "/tmp/circles_list.xml"  
           -->  
  <Input>"1"</Input>  
  <!-- If true (non-zero) we flip the input images around the horizontal axis.-->  
  <Input_FlipAroundHorizontalAxis>0</Input_FlipAroundHorizontalAxis>  
  <!-- Time delay between frames in case of camera. -->  
  <Input_Delay>100</Input_Delay>       
  <!-- How many frames to use, for calibration. -->  
  <Calibrate_NrOfFrameToUse>10</Calibrate_NrOfFrameToUse>  
  <!-- Consider only fy as a free parameter, the ratio fx/fy stays the same as in the input cameraMatrix.   
        Use or not setting. 0 - False Non-Zero - True-->  
  <Calibrate_FixAspectRatio> 1 </Calibrate_FixAspectRatio>  
  <!-- If true (non-zero) tangential distortion coefficients are set to zeros and stay zero.-->  
  <Calibrate_AssumeZeroTangentialDistortion>1</Calibrate_AssumeZeroTangentialDistortion>  
  <!-- If true (non-zero) the principal point is not changed during the global optimization.-->  
  <Calibrate_FixPrincipalPointAtTheCenter> 1 </Calibrate_FixPrincipalPointAtTheCenter>  
  <!-- The name of the output log file. -->  
  <Write_outputFileName>"out_camera_data.xml"</Write_outputFileName>  
  <!-- If true (non-zero) we write to the output file the feature points.-->  
  <Write_DetectedFeaturePoints>1</Write_DetectedFeaturePoints>  
  <!-- If true (non-zero) we write to the output file the extrinsic camera parameters.-->  
  <Write_extrinsicParameters>1</Write_extrinsicParameters>  
  <!-- If true (non-zero) we show after calibration the undistorted images.-->  
  <Show_UndistortedImage>1</Show_UndistortedImage>  
 </Settings>  
 </opencv_storage>
```

My code:
    #include

```
 #include <sstream>  
    #include <time.h>  

    #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>  
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>  
    #include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>  
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>  

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    void help()
    {
        cout << "This is a camera calibration sample." << endl
            << "Usage: calibration configurationFile" << endl
            << "Near the sample file you'll find the configuration file, which has detailed help of "
            "how to edit it. It may be any OpenCV supported file format XML/YAML." << endl;
    }
    class Settings
    {
    public:
        Settings() : goodInput(false) {}
        enum Pattern { NOT_EXISTING, CHESSBOARD, CIRCLES_GRID, ASYMMETRIC_CIRCLES_GRID };
        enum InputType { INVALID, CAMERA, VIDEO_FILE, IMAGE_LIST };

        void write(FileStorage& fs) const            //Write serialization for this class  
        {
            fs << "{" << "BoardSize_Width" << boardSize.width
                << "BoardSize_Height" << boardSize.height
                << "Square_Size" << squareSize
                << "Calibrate_Pattern" << patternToUse
                << "Calibrate_NrOfFrameToUse" << nrFrames
                << "Calibrate_FixAspectRatio" << aspectRatio
                << "Calibrate_AssumeZeroTangentialDistortion" << calibZeroTangentDist
                << "Calibrate_FixPrincipalPointAtTheCenter" << calibFixPrincipalPoint

                << "Write_DetectedFeaturePoints" << bwritePoints
                << "Write_extrinsicParameters" << bwriteExtrinsics
                << "Write_outputFileName" << outputFileName

                << "Show_UndistortedImage" << showUndistorsed

                << "Input_FlipAroundHorizontalAxis" << flipVertical
                << "Input_Delay" << delay
                << "Input" << input
                << "}";
        }
        void read(const FileNode& node)             //Read serialization for this class  
        {
            node["BoardSize_Width"] >> boardSize.width;
            node["BoardSize_Height"] >> boardSize.height;
            node["Calibrate_Pattern"] >> patternToUse;
            node["Square_Size"] >> squareSize;
            node["Calibrate_NrOfFrameToUse"] >> nrFrames;
            node["Calibrate_FixAspectRatio"] >> aspectRatio;
            node["Write_DetectedFeaturePoints"] >> bwritePoints;
            node["Write_extrinsicParameters"] >> bwriteExtrinsics;
            node["Write_outputFileName"] >> outputFileName;
            node["Calibrate_AssumeZeroTangentialDistortion"] >> calibZeroTangentDist;
            node["Calibrate_FixPrincipalPointAtTheCenter"] >> calibFixPrincipalPoint;
            node["Input_FlipAroundHorizontalAxis"] >> flipVertical;
            node["Show_UndistortedImage"] >> showUndistorsed;
            node["Input"] >> input;
            node["Input_Delay"] >> delay;
            interprate();
        }
        void interprate()
        {
            goodInput = true;
            if (boardSize.width <= 0 || boardSize.height <= 0)
            {
                cerr << "Invalid Board size: " << boardSize.width << " " << boardSize.height << endl;
                goodInput = false;
            }
            if (squareSize <= 10e-6)
            {
                cerr << "Invalid square size " << squareSize << endl;
                goodInput = false;
            }
            if (nrFrames <= 0)
            {
                cerr << "Invalid number of frames " << nrFrames << endl;
                goodInput = false;
            }

            if (input.empty())   // Check for valid input  
                inputType = INVALID;
            else
            {
                if (input[0] >= '0' && input[0] <= '9')
                {
                    stringstream ss(input);
                    ss >> cameraID;
                    inputType = CAMERA;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (readStringList(input, imageList))
                    {
                        inputType = IMAGE_LIST;
                        nrFrames = (nrFrames < imageList.size()) ? nrFrames : imageList.size();
                    }
                    else
                        inputType = VIDEO_FILE;
                }
                if (inputType == CAMERA)
                    inputCapture.open(cameraID);
                if (inputType == VIDEO_FILE)
                    inputCapture.open(input);
                if (inputType != IMAGE_LIST && !inputCapture.isOpened())
                    inputType = INVALID;
            }
            if (inputType == INVALID)
            {
                cerr << " Inexistent input: " << input;
                goodInput = false;
            }

            flag = 0;
            if (calibFixPrincipalPoint) flag |= CV_CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT;
            if (calibZeroTangentDist)  flag |= CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST;
            if (aspectRatio)      flag |= CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO;


            calibrationPattern = NOT_EXISTING;
            if (!patternToUse.compare("CHESSBOARD")) calibrationPattern = CHESSBOARD;
            if (!patternToUse.compare("CIRCLES_GRID")) calibrationPattern = CIRCLES_GRID;
            if (!patternToUse.compare("ASYMMETRIC_CIRCLES_GRID")) calibrationPattern = ASYMMETRIC_CIRCLES_GRID;
            if (calibrationPattern == NOT_EXISTING)
            {
                cerr << " Inexistent camera calibration mode: " << patternToUse << endl;
                goodInput = false;
            }
            atImageList = 0;

        }
        Mat nextImage()
        {
            Mat result;
            if (inputCapture.isOpened())
            {
                Mat view0;
                inputCapture >> view0;
                view0.copyTo(result);
            }
            else if (atImageList < (int)imageList.size())
                result = imread(imageList[atImageList++], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

            return result;
        }

        static bool readStringList(const string& filename, vector<string>& l)
        {
            l.clear();
            FileStorage fs(filename, FileStorage::READ);
            if (!fs.isOpened())
                return false;
            FileNode n = fs.getFirstTopLevelNode();
            if (n.type() != FileNode::SEQ)
                return false;
            FileNodeIterator it = n.begin(), it_end = n.end();
            for (; it != it_end; ++it)
                l.push_back((string)*it);
            return true;
        }
    public:
        Size boardSize;      // The size of the board -> Number of items by width and height  
        Pattern calibrationPattern;// One of the Chessboard, circles, or asymmetric circle pattern  
        float squareSize;     // The size of a square in your defined unit (point, millimeter,etc).  
        int nrFrames;       // The number of frames to use from the input for calibration  
        float aspectRatio;     // The aspect ratio  
        int delay;         // In case of a video input   
        bool bwritePoints;     // Write detected feature points  
        bool bwriteExtrinsics;   // Write extrinsic parameters  
        bool calibZeroTangentDist; // Assume zero tangential distortion  
        bool calibFixPrincipalPoint;// Fix the principal point at the center  
        bool flipVertical;     // Flip the captured images around the horizontal axis  
        string outputFileName;   // The name of the file where to write  
        bool showUndistorsed;    // Show undistorted images after calibration  
        string input;        // The input ->   



        int cameraID;
        vector<string> imageList;
        int atImageList;
        VideoCapture inputCapture;
        InputType inputType;
        bool goodInput;
        int flag;

    private:
        string patternToUse;


    };

    void write(FileStorage& fs, const std::string&, const Settings& x)
    {
        x.write(fs);
    }
    void read(const FileNode& node, Settings& x, const Settings& default_value = Settings())
    {
        if (node.empty())
            x = default_value;
        else
            x.read(node);
    }

    enum { DETECTION = 0, CAPTURING = 1, CALIBRATED = 2 };

    bool runCalibrationAndSave(Settings& s, Size imageSize, Mat& cameraMatrix, Mat& distCoeffs,
        vector<vector<Point2f> > imagePoints);

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        help();
        Settings s;
        const string inputSettingsFile = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "in_VID5.xml";
        FileStorage fs(inputSettingsFile, FileStorage::READ); // Read the settings  
        if (!fs.isOpened())
        {
            cout << "Could not open the configuration file: \"" << inputSettingsFile << "\"" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        fs["Settings"] >> s;
        fs.release();                     // close Settings file  

        if (!s.goodInput)
        {
            cout << "Invalid input detected. Application stopping. " << endl;
            return -1;
        }

        vector<vector<Point2f> > imagePoints;
        Mat cameraMatrix, distCoeffs;
        Size imageSize;
        int mode = s.inputType == Settings::IMAGE_LIST ? CAPTURING : DETECTION;
        clock_t prevTimestamp = 0;
        const Scalar RED(0, 0, 255), GREEN(0, 255, 0);
        const char ESC_KEY = 27;

        for (int i = 0;; ++i)
        {
            Mat view;
            bool blinkOutput = false;

            view = s.nextImage();

            //----- If no more image, or got enough, then stop calibration and show result -------------  
            if (mode == CAPTURING && imagePoints.size() >= (unsigned)s.nrFrames)
            {
                if (runCalibrationAndSave(s, imageSize, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, imagePoints))
                    mode = CALIBRATED;
                else
                    mode = DETECTION;
            }
            if (view.empty())     // If no more images then run calibration, save and stop loop.  
            {
                if (imagePoints.size() > 0)
                    runCalibrationAndSave(s, imageSize, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, imagePoints);
                break;
            }


            imageSize = view.size(); // Format input image.  
            if (s.flipVertical)  flip(view, view, 0);

            vector<Point2f> pointBuf;

            bool found;
            switch (s.calibrationPattern) // Find feature points on the input format  
            {
            case Settings::CHESSBOARD:
                found = findChessboardCorners(view, s.boardSize, pointBuf,
                    CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK | CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);
                break;
            case Settings::CIRCLES_GRID:
                found = findCirclesGrid(view, s.boardSize, pointBuf);
                break;
            case Settings::ASYMMETRIC_CIRCLES_GRID:
                found = findCirclesGrid(view, s.boardSize, pointBuf, CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID);
                break;
            }

            if (found)        // If done with success,   
            {
                // improve the found corners' coordinate accuracy for chessboard  
                if (s.calibrationPattern == Settings::CHESSBOARD)
                {
                    Mat viewGray;
                    cvtColor(view, viewGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
                    cornerSubPix(viewGray, pointBuf, Size(11, 11),
                        Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
                }

                if (mode == CAPTURING && // For camera only take new samples after delay time  
                    (!s.inputCapture.isOpened() || clock() - prevTimestamp > s.delay*1e-3*CLOCKS_PER_SEC))
                {
                    imagePoints.push_back(pointBuf);
                    prevTimestamp = clock();
                    blinkOutput = s.inputCapture.isOpened();
                }

                // Draw the corners.   
                drawChessboardCorners(view, s.boardSize, Mat(pointBuf), found);
            }

            //----------------------------- Output Text ------------------------------------------------  
            string msg = (mode == CAPTURING) ? "100/100" :
                mode == CALIBRATED ? "Calibrated" : "Press 'g' to start";
            int baseLine = 0;
            Size textSize = getTextSize(msg, 1, 1, 1, &baseLine);
            Point textOrigin(view.cols - 2 * textSize.width - 10, view.rows - 2 * baseLine - 10);

            if (mode == CAPTURING)
            {
                if (s.showUndistorsed)
                    msg = format("%d/%d Undist", (int)imagePoints.size(), s.nrFrames);
                else
                    msg = format("%d/%d", (int)imagePoints.size(), s.nrFrames);
            }

            putText(view, msg, textOrigin, 1, 1, mode == CALIBRATED ? GREEN : RED);

            if (blinkOutput)
                bitwise_not(view, view);

            //------------------------- Video capture output undistorted ------------------------------  
            if (mode == CALIBRATED && s.showUndistorsed)
            {
                Mat temp = view.clone();
                undistort(temp, view, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs);
            }

            //------------------------------ Show image and check for input commands -------------------  
            imshow("Image View", view);
            char key = waitKey(s.inputCapture.isOpened() ? 50 : s.delay);

            if (key == ESC_KEY)
                break;

            if (key == 'u' && mode == CALIBRATED)
                s.showUndistorsed = !s.showUndistorsed;

            if (s.inputCapture.isOpened() && key == 'g')
            {
                mode = CAPTURING;
                imagePoints.clear();
            }
        }

        // -----------------------Show the undistorted image for the image list ------------------------  
        if (s.inputType == Settings::IMAGE_LIST && s.showUndistorsed)
        {
            Mat view, rview, map1, map2;
            initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, Mat(),
                getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, imageSize, 1, imageSize, 0),
                imageSize, CV_16SC2, map1, map2);

            for (int i = 0; i < (int)s.imageList.size(); i++)
            {
                view = imread(s.imageList[i], 1);
                if (view.empty())
                    continue;
                remap(view, rview, map1, map2, INTER_LINEAR);
                imshow("Image View", rview);
                char c = waitKey();
                if (c == ESC_KEY || c == 'q' || c == 'Q')
                    break;
            }
        }


        return 0;
    }

    double computeReprojectionErrors(const vector<vector<Point3f> >& objectPoints,
        const vector<vector<Point2f> >& imagePoints,
        const vector<Mat>& rvecs, const vector<Mat>& tvecs,
        const Mat& cameraMatrix, const Mat& distCoeffs,
        vector<float>& perViewErrors)
    {
        vector<Point2f> imagePoints2;
        int i, totalPoints = 0;
        double totalErr = 0, err;
        perViewErrors.resize(objectPoints.size());

        for (i = 0; i < (int)objectPoints.size(); ++i)
        {
            projectPoints(Mat(objectPoints[i]), rvecs[i], tvecs[i], cameraMatrix,
                distCoeffs, imagePoints2);
            err = norm(Mat(imagePoints[i]), Mat(imagePoints2), CV_L2);

            int n = (int)objectPoints[i].size();
            perViewErrors[i] = (float)std::sqrt(err*err / n);
            totalErr += err*err;
            totalPoints += n;
        }

        return std::sqrt(totalErr / totalPoints);
    }

    void calcBoardCornerPositions(Size boardSize, float squareSize, vector<Point3f>& corners,
        Settings::Pattern patternType /*= Settings::CHESSBOARD*/)
    {
        corners.clear();

        switch (patternType)
        {
        case Settings::CHESSBOARD:
        case Settings::CIRCLES_GRID:
            for (int i = 0; i < boardSize.height; ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j < boardSize.width; ++j)
                    corners.push_back(Point3f(float(j*squareSize), float(i*squareSize), 0));
            break;

        case Settings::ASYMMETRIC_CIRCLES_GRID:
            for (int i = 0; i < boardSize.height; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < boardSize.width; j++)
                    corners.push_back(Point3f(float((2 * j + i % 2)*squareSize), float(i*squareSize), 0));
            break;
        }
    }

    bool runCalibration(Settings& s, Size& imageSize, Mat& cameraMatrix, Mat& distCoeffs,
        vector<vector<Point2f> > imagePoints, vector<Mat>& rvecs, vector<Mat>& tvecs,
        vector<float>& reprojErrs, double& totalAvgErr)
    {

        cameraMatrix = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);
        if (s.flag & CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO)
            cameraMatrix.at<double>(0, 0) = 1.0;

        distCoeffs = Mat::zeros(8, 1, CV_64F);

        vector<vector<Point3f> > objectPoints(1);
        calcBoardCornerPositions(s.boardSize, s.squareSize, objectPoints[0], s.calibrationPattern);

        objectPoints.resize(imagePoints.size(), objectPoints[0]);

        //Find intrinsic and extrinsic camera parameters  
        double rms = calibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePoints, imageSize, cameraMatrix,
            distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs, s.flag | CV_CALIB_FIX_K4 | CV_CALIB_FIX_K5);

        cout << "Re-projection error reported by calibrateCamera: " << rms << endl;

        bool ok = checkRange(cameraMatrix) && checkRange(distCoeffs);

        totalAvgErr = computeReprojectionErrors(objectPoints, imagePoints,
            rvecs, tvecs, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, reprojErrs);

        return ok;
    }

    // Print camera parameters to the output file  
    void saveCameraParams(Settings& s, Size& imageSize, Mat& cameraMatrix, Mat& distCoeffs,
        const vector<Mat>& rvecs, const vector<Mat>& tvecs,
        const vector<float>& reprojErrs, const vector<vector<Point2f> >& imagePoints,
        double totalAvgErr)
    {
        FileStorage fs(s.outputFileName, FileStorage::WRITE);

        time_t t;
        time(&t);
        struct tm *t2 = localtime(&t);
        char buf[1024];
        strftime(buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, "%c", t2);

        fs << "calibration_Time" << buf;

        if (!rvecs.empty() || !reprojErrs.empty())
            fs << "nrOfFrames" << (int)std::max(rvecs.size(), reprojErrs.size());
        fs << "image_Width" << imageSize.width;
        fs << "image_Height" << imageSize.height;
        fs << "board_Width" << s.boardSize.width;
        fs << "board_Height" << s.boardSize.height;
        fs << "square_Size" << s.squareSize;

        if (s.flag & CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO)
            fs << "FixAspectRatio" << s.aspectRatio;

        if (s.flag)
        {
            sprintf(buf, "flags: %s%s%s%s",
                s.flag & CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS ? " +use_intrinsic_guess" : "",
                s.flag & CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO ? " +fix_aspectRatio" : "",
                s.flag & CV_CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT ? " +fix_principal_point" : "",
                s.flag & CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST ? " +zero_tangent_dist" : "");
            cvWriteComment(*fs, buf, 0);

        }

        fs << "flagValue" << s.flag;

        fs << "Camera_Matrix" << cameraMatrix;
        fs << "Distortion_Coefficients" << distCoeffs;

        fs << "Avg_Reprojection_Error" << totalAvgErr;
        if (!reprojErrs.empty())
            fs << "Per_View_Reprojection_Errors" << Mat(reprojErrs);

        if (!rvecs.empty() && !tvecs.empty())
        {
            CV_Assert(rvecs[0].type() == tvecs[0].type());
            Mat bigmat((int)rvecs.size(), 6, rvecs[0].type());
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)rvecs.size(); i++)
            {
                Mat r = bigmat(Range(i, i + 1), Range(0, 3));
                Mat t = bigmat(Range(i, i + 1), Range(3, 6));

                CV_Assert(rvecs[i].rows == 3 && rvecs[i].cols == 1);
                CV_Assert(tvecs[i].rows == 3 && tvecs[i].cols == 1);
                //*.t() is MatExpr (not Mat) so we can use assignment operator  
                r = rvecs[i].t();
                t = tvecs[i].t();
            }
            cvWriteComment(*fs, "a set of 6-tuples (rotation vector + translation vector) for each view", 0);
            fs << "Extrinsic_Parameters" << bigmat;
        }

        if (!imagePoints.empty())
        {
            Mat imagePtMat((int)imagePoints.size(), imagePoints[0].size(), CV_32FC2);
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)imagePoints.size(); i++)
            {
                Mat r = imagePtMat.row(i).reshape(2, imagePtMat.cols);
                Mat imgpti(imagePoints[i]);
                imgpti.copyTo(r);
            }
            fs << "Image_points" << imagePtMat;
        }
    }

    bool runCalibrationAndSave(Settings& s, Size imageSize, Mat& cameraMatrix, Mat& distCoeffs, vector<vector<Point2f> > imagePoints)
    {
        vector<Mat> rvecs, tvecs;
        vector<float> reprojErrs;
        double totalAvgErr = 0;

        bool ok = runCalibration(s, imageSize, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, imagePoints, rvecs, tvecs,
            reprojErrs, totalAvgErr);
        cout << (ok ? "Calibration succeeded" : "Calibration failed")
            << ". avg re projection error = " << totalAvgErr;

        if (ok)
            saveCameraParams(s, imageSize, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs, reprojErrs,
                imagePoints, totalAvgErr);
        return ok;
    }
```

Comment: Please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking a good question.

Comment: Someone help me pls

Comment: can somebody help me?